# working with dataset in sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a dataset is in this format in .csv

```
id,interaction_flag,x_coordinate,y_coordinate,z_coordinate,hydrophobicity_kd,hydrophobicity_ww,hydrophobicity_hh,surface_tension,charge_cooh,charge_nh3,charge_r,alpha_helix,beta_strand,turn,van_der_walls,mol_wt,solublity  
229810,1,-33.8675148907451,-110.273691995647,100.021824089754,0.129381338742408,0.129381338742408,0.129381338742408,57.9996957403639,2.20539553752535,9.55985801217038,4.47146044624688,1.08064908722114,1.20135902636915,0.611653144016251,145.232251521298,107.951643002026,21.5344036511141        
229811,1,-26.9070290467923,-117.172163712053,106.980243932766,0.922048681541592,0.922048681541592,0.922048681541592,58.5383367139972,2.03983772819472,9.23210953346856,1.58401622717997,0.84178498985806,1.0387626774848,0.921703853955354,124.73630831643,84.1570182555755,10.7648600405665
```

I am trying to get Receiver Operating Characteristics (ROC) from this data using this link : http://scikit-learn.org/0.11/auto_examples/plot_roc.html

My target is interaction_flag column and test is all columns after interaction_flag.
But, my program continue running in never ending state.

When I run the test example given in that link, it runs within a moment.

Can anyone let me know what wrong I am doing? or do I need to so something else to load my data like iris?

my code :

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc

training = 'dataset/training_5000_col.csv'
test = 'dataset/test_5000_col.csv'

random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)

# Import some data to play with
#iris = datasets.load_iris()
#X = iris.data
#y = iris.target
X = []
y = []
for line in open(training):
    z = line.rstrip().split(',')
y.append(int(z[2]))
tmp = []
for a in range(5, 15):
    tmp.append(float(z[a]))
X.append(tmp)
X_train = np.array(X)
y_train = np.array(y)



X1 = []
y1 = []
for line in open(test):
z = line.rstrip().split(',')
y1.append(int(z[2]))
tmp = []
for a in range(5, 15):
    tmp.append(float(z[a]))
X1.append(tmp)
X_test = np.array(X1)
y_test = np.array(y1)

# Run classifier
classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True)
probas_ = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test)

# Compute ROC curve and area the curve
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, probas_[:, 1])
print "y_test : ", y_test
print "fpr : ", fpr
print "tpr : ", tpr
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
print "Area under the ROC curve : %f" % roc_auc

# Plot ROC curve
pl.clf()
pl.plot(fpr, tpr, label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc)
pl.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')
pl.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
pl.ylim([0.0, 1.0])
pl.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
pl.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
pl.title('Receiver operating characteristic example')
pl.legend(loc="lower right")
pl.show()
```

my .csv file is at  : http://pastebin.com/iet5xQW2
how I will plot roc with this .csv

Comment: and where is your program? can you please post it?

Comment: in my program I have first retrieved the interaction_flag in one list and other test data in other list and then passed to the fit function.

Comment: First comment: the link you provide is referencing the documentation of a very old version of scikit-learn. Replace the 0.11 by stable in the URL to get the up to date documentation. 

Then please edit your question to print the `shape`, `dtype` and the first 5 lines of the `X_train` and `y_train` arrays.

Comment: it is of 0.14 version only

Comment: please guide me step by step. I am stucked there from long and I dont find any way with .csv I have to get roc

Answer (score 2):

You need to have two different labels in order to plot the ROC curve.
The following example works for me if I add some 0 labels in your data. I have used pandas to read the data, rest is same as sklearn example.

Also, you need to split the dataset into training and test set to plot the ROC curve on the test set.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import interp
import pylab as pl

from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold




def data(filename):
    X = pd.read_table(filename, sep=',', warn_bad_lines=True, error_bad_lines=True, low_memory = False)

    X = np.asarray(X)

    data = X[:,2:]
    labels = X[:,1]
    print np.unique(labels)

    return data, labels




filename = '../data/sodata.csv'
X, y = data(filename)

###############################################################################
# Classification and ROC analysis

# Run classifier with cross-validation and plot ROC curves
cv = StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=6)
classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True, random_state=0)

mean_tpr = 0.0
mean_fpr = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
all_tpr = []

for i, (train, test) in enumerate(cv):
    probas_ = classifier.fit(X[train], y[train]).predict_proba(X[test])
    # Compute ROC curve and area the curve
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y[test], probas_[:, 1])
    mean_tpr += interp(mean_fpr, fpr, tpr)
    mean_tpr[0] = 0.0
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
    pl.plot(fpr, tpr, lw=1, label='ROC fold %d (area = %0.2f)' % (i, roc_auc))

pl.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], '--', color=(0.6, 0.6, 0.6), label='Luck')

mean_tpr /= len(cv)
mean_tpr[-1] = 1.0
mean_auc = auc(mean_fpr, mean_tpr)
pl.plot(mean_fpr, mean_tpr, 'k--',
        label='Mean ROC (area = %0.2f)' % mean_auc, lw=2)

pl.xlim([-0.05, 1.05])
pl.ylim([-0.05, 1.05])
pl.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
pl.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
pl.title('Receiver operating characteristic example')
pl.legend(loc="lower right")
pl.show()
```

Comment: thanks I will check. how much time it takes for probas? since I am runnig it frmo 3-4 hours and it is still running?

Comment: it take me a few seconds on the dataset you have provided. you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: since its running whole day. can you tell me what you do with dataset I have provided in pastebin link in detail ?

Comment: I got it. can you tell me same about http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_precision_recall.html